# Creating WebWorker Throws DOM Exception 18 in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I'm trying to create a webworker and I'm getting a DOM Exception when trying to construct the worker in Safari 5.1.7. This happens on some domains and only in Safari. For example, if you go to CNN.com and type var `test = new Worker("foo.js")` , you will get a DOM exception 18. Does anyone has any ideas of why this might be happening? Thanks

Just adding some more details.. I have tested this on the new version of Safari and it does not have the same issue. Another example of a domain that seems to be having a similar issue is nordstrom.com

Comment: http://CNN.com/something does not seem to be a script to me. Please tell us what you are actually doing, maybe provide some code or even a demo

Comment: it does not matter what the script path is, you can not load any script... you should be able to replicate the problem by just typing test = new Worker("something") into the console

Comment: Could it be that request to "foo.js" does not respond with content-type of "text/javascript" and browser is too "picky" about this? If content type is "text/html" (or any other) it might be that browser "thinks" you're trying to interact with  DOM which is not allowed in web worker.

Comment: @Ramunas that is not the case, I'm implementing this on a client's website and the path does lead to a valid script on the same domain. unfortunately, I can not share the actual implementation here for privacy concerns.

Comment: This problem occurs because "www.cnn.com" remaps their document.domain from "www.cnn.com" to "cnn.com". I figured this out by proxying out the script the remaps document.domain; when I did that, WebWorkers worked correctly. I think this might be a Safari 5.1 bug (this doesn't happen in Safari 6). The only solution I can foresee would be to load in the script that uses the WebWorker before you load in the script that remaps the domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in old versions of WebKit: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67978

It happens when you set 'document.domain' and then try to create a worker after the domain is set. The only workaround is to create the worker prior to setting 'document.domain'.